# I have a stored procedure how to store its output and display in .NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, data-binding

I have a form with a section called search, where user enters a name and it search for 3 tables and displays the output based on the search that in which it exist or not.

In below example i am taking the query input as "**Joe**" and it will lookup in the table for its existence and will give the tabular format.
Now i am stuck that i have created table, sqlprocedure but i don't know how to call sql procedure when user enter name and click on search button, and the sqlprocudure is called and output is displayed without refreshing the page.

Please any code help will be appreciated.

**DESCRIPTION IN EG:** i have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Name Nvarchar(10));
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Name Nvarchar(10));
CREATE TABLE Table3 (Name Nvarchar(10));

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Joe');
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES ('Joe');
```

and i have this SQL Procedure:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as Table1
      ,CASE WHEN t2.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as Table2
      ,CASE WHEN t3.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as Table3
    FROM Table1 t1
    FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
    FULL JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.Name = t3.Name OR t3.Name = t2.Name
    AND t1.Name = 'Joe' AND t2.Name = 'Joe' AND t3.Name = 'Joe'
```

Now problem is i am not that much good at .NET just tell me after putting this query in DB in sqlprocedure section.. How should i call the output from this to my frontend when the search query is processed.

i hope that helps.. here is the sqlfiddle for the query :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f3ad/17

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Aspx Page add datalist

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="gvData">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ColumnName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ColumnName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ColumnName
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("Table1").ToString()%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("Table2").ToString()%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("Table3").ToString()%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
</table>
```

and aspx.Cs Add this method

```
public void BindData()
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.CommandText = "GetProduct";

    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        gvData.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        gvData.DataBind();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();

        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: so that will be the sql query then how it will display the output.

Comment: dbConnectionString means pass your conection strimg like
**Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=DatabseName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=YourSQLUseName;Password=YourSQLPassword**
and Use repeater or gridview for Data display.

Comment: Yea that i already know.. i want to know how to display result using gridview or whatever how to bind the query.. :(

Comment: I have Edited My code. And Get data From Store Procedure and Bind  Control Using Store Procedure. add your Column Name In Eval Function(in aspx Page).

Comment: Thanks for that  ! just a a question what is this line doing : cmd.CommandText = "GetProduct";

Comment: i have a issue here.. this code is creating issue not working.. :(

Comment: Use **ColumnName** instead of your column like (Table1,Table2,Table3) in DataList(gvData).

Comment: yea got that solved ! Thanks anyway. but i have new issue.. the output is not showing any header.. so how to add manual text header to columns and improve this shit output like this:  http://s6.postimg.org/7nnqlzb5t/erer.png

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy ! Can you send me your email id or someway.. so i can contact you in future if required.